How to show subtracting from both sides of an equation?
What is the easiest way to show subtracting from both sides of an equation (or other operations) in Latex?
I would want the subtraction roughly lined up with the equation. For example:

4x + 7 = 10
   - 7   -7
4x     = 3


Welcome to TeX SE. have you tried anything to achieve this?

Hi Alain, I've tried using an align environment, but it adds extra spacing the equation that I don't want. I guess I was wondering if there's some standard way to do this since it's a pretty common set up for high school/middle school math assignments.

Try something like this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        4x + 7             &= 10           \\
        \phantom{4x} -7    &\phantom{=} -7 \\
        4x \phantom{{}+7}  &= 3 
    \end{align*}    
\end{document}

The extra group {} in phantom is inspired from this post
Output:

Edit: I personally would typeset the equation something like this:
    \begin{align*}
        4x + 7 &= 10 \qquad \big| -7\\
        4x   &= 3 
    \end{align*}   

Output:

But it's a matter of taste.
